# I can't figure out why this throws an exception?

Tags: java

This seems easy. I have tried debugging it, and it keeps throwing an exception. Sanity check please?

```
int[] array = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
for(int i = 0; i <= array.length; i++) {
 System.out.println(array[i]);
}
```

Comment: `i < array.length` instead of `i <= array.length`. Just remember that indexes start at 0, so naturally, they must also end at length-1.

Comment: duplicates somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your for loop to:

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
```

Answer (score 5):

This:

```
i <= array.length
```

Will loop from 0-6.  As the exception is undoubtedly telling you (and you really should read it), there is no index `6` in your array.

Try this:

```
i < array.length
```

Answer (score 2):

You can always iterate the array from `0` to `array.length-1`. You are trying to access the element at index which is out of bound of array length.

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayIndexOutOfBounds`, since arrays in java are 0based, the highest index of an array with length 'l' is 'l-1'.